# POSTGRESQL position substring

Tags: sql, postgresql, position, substring

I have an easy problem (I think) that I couldn't solve:
I have many tag like this:
`'FOOT05_00120_RIG_1_GOAL_K'`
but the length is not the same for all the records and I need a query to take all the character before the last `_`, does anybody how can I do?

(It could be within such a query:

```
SELECT tag FROM Football
```

)

Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem seems almost designed for `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(tag, '(.*)_[^_]*$', '\1')
from football;
```

The regular expression is interpreted as:

```
'(.*)_[^_]*$'
-^ remember this expression for a reference
--^ any character
---^ any number of times
----^ followed by _
-----^ followed by any characters that are not _
----------^ any number of times
-----------^ at the end of the string
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REVERSE` function to determine the position of last hyphen, and then  apply `SUBSTRING()` along with `LENGTH()` function such as

```
WITH Football AS
(
 SELECT 'FOOT05_00120_RIG_1_GOAL_K' AS tag
)
SELECT SUBSTRING( tag, 1, LENGTH(tag) - POSITION('_' IN REVERSE(tag)) ) AS Result
  FROM Football
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=2ecdf05f9907a497b8510cb3d778ee62)</kbd>